# Why speaks basic http authentication always of a username

Tags: http, authentication

In [RFC 2617 HTTP Authentication: Basic and Digest Access Authentication](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt) they speak always of username and password for the authentication.

Why should I choose to take a username as identifier for a website? Usernames are often hard to choose a not existing one or one which is unique. But everyone getting an account somewhere has an email which is unique.

Why does the RFC not speak of something abstract like a unique string identifier? That would make much more sense to me where everyone logs into his account with his email...

When someone starts with security/authentication the first thing he will think reading the RFC 2617 that he can not do basic auth because I want email + password. What am I missing here?

Comment: That RFC is sufficiently abstract: `userid = *<TEXT excluding ":">`. Not “user-*name*” but “user-*id*”. HTTP does not make any further assumptions about this id, which might be an email. It is up to the server/the application to interpret this id.

Comment: In my above posted RFC2617 link I can find the words "username" 29 times. So they make assumptions?

Comment: That RFC discusses two authentication methods: “Basic Auth” and “Digest Auth“. As it happens, the section about basic auth only refers to user-ids, but it's useless to read too much into such a minor choice of words. **The point is**, the only restrictions to these IDs are that they don't contain control characters, line breaks, or colons. Anything else incl. email addresses is allowed as far as HTTP is concerned. **It is up to the server** what IDs are created and authenticated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here isn't so much the spec, as it is your interpretation.

It seems there's a habit among computer professional to always expect verbally spoken and written language to have the same well-defined meaning as programming languages (i.e. if you use *this* word in a sentence, you *must* mean this).

What's worse is that different people have different preconceptions of the exact and true meaning of certain words and that leads to all kinds of discussions, arguments and all-out battles. Here's an example of someone trying to understand a difference between fragile and brutal and you can read my ranty answer: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/131240/difference-between-brittle-and-fragile/131259#131259

You have fallen into the same trap with this auth spec. They mention "username" and "password" but all it really means is that your credentials have two parts: public part that everyone knows about and can uniquely identify you by and a private secret part that only the user knows so he can get authenticated.  But at the end, the public part (aka a "username") can be just about anything you want, including someone's e-mail, or in some dumb cases, their social security# or in corporate case their unique identifier which puts then on the same level as all other resources.

Answer (score 0):

At no point does it say that your email address (as one example) cannot be your username. At no point does it say that the website issuing the login cannot insist that your email address (as one example) is your username.

The term for a string used to identify a user, is `username`. Whether it can always, never, or sometimes be an email address is out of implementation-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

In general, being more precisely specific with word choice can at times make communication more difficult and cumbersome. The authors of the document assumed that their audience would understand that "username", "user name", "user ID", "UID", "userid", "user-id", *ad infinitum*, are all considered synonymous for the purposes of HTTP-Auth discussion - and indeed most discussions in this field.

Your username is the name that the "user" (and their associated account) is known by. This 
"name" "identifies" the user uniquely. Their name is their ID, their passport, their Globally Unique Prearranged Realm-Dependent Identification Resource, etc.

In most cases I've encountered, these terms are used interchangeably, freely, and it is simply assumed that - being a part of the common culture - you'll understand what they mean as easily as you needn't have the precise meaning of "server/client" defined or their relationship made explicit.

So, why don't they speak more abstractly or precisely? Tradition, and it works. It is unlikely any system was ever mis-configured or improperly designed because of the word choice, and the valid format for a user-id is defined. User/pass is just so common a construct as to be assumed to be instantaneously understand by the target audience.